# Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'direct' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++, allegro5

In this part of code is an error. It says

> "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'direct' is being used
>   without being initialized."

How can I fix this error ?

```
bool loop=true;
int direct;

al_install_keyboard();

ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = al_create_timer (0.4);
ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *keystroke = al_create_event_queue();
al_register_event_source(keystroke ,al_get_keyboard_event_source() );
al_register_event_source (keystroke , al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
al_start_timer(timer);

do{
    ALLEGRO_EVENT input;
    al_wait_for_event(keystroke , &input );
    if (input.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN){
        switch(input.keyboard.keycode){
        case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN: direct=DOWN; break;
        case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP : direct=UP;break;
        case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT: direct=LEFT;break;
        case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT: direct=RIGHT;break;
        case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE: loop= false;
        }
    }

    if(input.type==ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER){
        switch(direct){
        case DOWN: moove_snake(DOWN) ; break;
        case UP: moove_snake(UP) ; break;
        case LEFT: moove_snake(LEFT) ; break;
        case RIGHT: moove_snake(RIGHT) ; break;
        }
    }

}while (loop);
```

Comment: Always initialize variables to some default value, this is a GOOD PRACTICE and also make the piece of code less prone to attacks (assume the case of pointer on stack not properly initialized). Also note there is no default under *switch(input.key...)* which could result in **direct** not getting initialized and 'direct' being used in **switch(direct)**.

Answer (score 9):

initialize it :)

```
int direct = 0;
```

Comment: @AbrahamyanSamvel This is not true.

Comment: It will sure help.  Try again.

Answer (score 3):

If the first if condition `if (input.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)` is false and the second one `if(input.type==ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)` is true, you are using `switch` with an uninitialized variable (int direct). This means that the variable is pointing to random bits in the memory and your compiler doesn't like that fact.

It's easy to fix by initializing the variable in the beginning. For example:
`int direct = UP;`

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried to initialize it and it did not work, then likely you have a problem elsewhere in the code that the parser just happens to fail on this line. Look above the `int direct;` line.

Check that all your curly braces match, that you have semi colons at the ends of lines, and that everything else generally looks good.

If you don't find it, comment out everything starting at `int direct;` and go from there.

Comment: everything is OK . I have compiled the same code many times without any errors .  I have tried to comment everything starting from int direct=0; and even after that the same error occurs . It seems my compiler is going crazy :)

Comment: Which version of which compiler? I would go back to the last changes you made before it started complaining and comment them out. If that doesn't locate the issue, comment EVERYTHING out except for minimum bare-bones with the `int direct=1234;` line included. Certainly your compiler isn't silly enough to say `int direct=1234;` is uninitialized. :-)

Comment: I ave fixed this problem simply by copying the code and pasting it in another new project :)

Answer (score 0):

READ CAREFULLY!! When the message appears, you have to choose break instead of continue before closing your application. If it still doesn't work, put static method before the variable like

```
static int direct;
```